# Regex for accent insensitive replacement in python

Tags: python, regex, unicode, non-ascii-characters, accent-insensitive

In Python 3, I'd like to be able to use `re.sub()` in an "accent-insensitive" way, as we can do with the `re.I` flag for case-insensitive substitution.

Could be something like a `re.IGNOREACCENTS` flag:

```
original_text = "¿It's 80°C, I'm drinking a café in a cafe with Chloë。"
accent_regex = r'a café'
re.sub(accent_regex, 'X', original_text, flags=re.IGNOREACCENTS)
```

This would lead to "¿It's 80°C, I'm drinking X in X with Chloë。" (note that there's still an accent on "Chloë") instead of "¿It's 80°C, I'm drinking X in a cafe with Chloë。" in real python.

I think that such a flag doesn't exist. So what would be the best option to do this? Using `re.finditer` and `unidecode` on both `original_text` and `accent_regex` and then replace by splitting the string? Or modifying all characters in the `accent_regex` by their accented variants, for instance: `r'[cç][aàâ]f[éèêë]'`?

Comment: `Could be something like...` @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: What you are looking for is a equivalence class - though I don't know any python regex module that supports them. Syntax is usually like `[[=a=]]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`unidecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) is often mentioned for removing accents in Python, but it also does more than that : it converts `'°'` to `'deg'`, which might not be the desired output.

[`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) seems to have [enough functionality to remove accents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39612904/6419007).

## With any pattern

This method should work with any pattern and any text.

You can temporarily remove the accents from both the text and regex pattern. The match information from [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) (start and end indices) can be used to modify the original, accented text.

Note that the matches must be reversed in order to not modify the following indices.

```
import re
import unicodedata

original_text = "I'm drinking a 80° café in a cafe with Chloë, François Déporte and Francois Deporte."

accented_pattern = r'a café|François Déporte'

def remove_accents(s):
    return ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))

print(remove_accents('äöüßéèiìììíàáç'))
# aoußeeiiiiiaac

pattern = re.compile(remove_accents(accented_pattern))

modified_text = original_text
matches = list(re.finditer(pattern, remove_accents(original_text)))

for match in matches[::-1]:
    modified_text = modified_text[:match.start()] + 'X' + modified_text[match.end():]

print(modified_text)
# I'm drinking a 80° café in X with Chloë, X and X.
```

## If pattern is a word or a set of words

You could :

- remove the accents out of your pattern words and save them in a set for fast lookup
- look for every word in your text with `\w+`
- remove the accents from the word:

  - If it matches, replace by `X`
  - If it doesn't match, leave the word untouched

---

```
import re
from unidecode import unidecode

original_text = "I'm drinking a café in a cafe with Chloë."

def remove_accents(string):
    return unidecode(string)

accented_words = ['café', 'français']

words_to_remove = set(remove_accents(word) for word in accented_words)

def remove_words(matchobj):
    word = matchobj.group(0)
    if remove_accents(word) in words_to_remove:
        return 'X'
    else:
        return word

print(re.sub('\w+', remove_words, original_text))
# I'm drinking a X in a X with Chloë.
```

Comment: Thanks, this method is smart! How to modify it to replace not only words but also n-gram? (I edited my question to take this option into account, for instance to replace "François Déporte" in a text where only "Francois Deporte" appears)

Comment: @AntoineDusséaux: No problem, the first method works fine.

Comment: I initially thought it would work but after a few tests this method failed if the length of the unidecoded string is not the same as the original one. For instance `unidecode('°')` is `'deg'`, so if `original_text = "I'm drinking a 18C° hot café in a cafe with Chloë, François Déporte and Francois Deporte."` you get `'I'm drinking a 18C° hot café in a Xith Chloë, FrXnd FrX'`. What would be another way to unidecode and keep the length constant?

Comment: @AntoineDusséaux: Not cool. :-/ You could replace `°` by `@` or `#` in the temporary string, before applying `unidecode`. I don't know of any other method which could remove accents while keeping the string length constant.

Comment: @AntoineDusséaux: I found an alternative with `unicodedata`. No need for external package and as far as I know, it only removes the accents.

Comment: Smart! I tried everything to break your solution and it seems it doesn't work with `'string_to_change = 'äöüßéèiìììíàáç°。阿bcqf反題梓z≤«»Ωﬁñ한か¿？！''` ;) so I changed it a little bit: `return ''.join((unidecode.unidecode(c) if len(unidecode.unidecode(c)) == len(c) else c for c in s))` and it seems to work fine!

Comment: @AntoineDusséaux: Unicode can be so complex that it's pretty easy to break any code with it.

Comment: Sure, for instance I realized some Unicode characters would be replaced with regex special characters, for instance Chinese dot `。` becomes `.` and then matches everything!

Comment: To avoid this we could escape all characters: `return ''.join(re.escape(unidecode.unidecode(c)) if len(unidecode.unidecode(c)) == len(c) else re.escape(c) for c in s)` (tested with `string_to_change = 'äöüßéèiìììíàáç°。阿bcqf反題梓z≤«»Ωﬁñ한か¿⸼？！..·⁂‖¦•+⸮…'`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142923/discussion-between-antoine-dusseaux-and-eric-duminil).

Comment: You may want to use `'NFKD'` instead of `'NFD'` to handle character equivalences, e.g. U+2160 (ROMAN NUMERAL ONE) is in NFKD the same as U+0049 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode):

```
$ pip install unidecode
```

In your program:

```
from unidecode import unidecode

original_text = "I'm drinking a café in a cafe."
unidecoded_text = unidecode(original_text)
regex = r'cafe'
re.sub(regex, 'X', unidecoded_text)
```

Comment: Thanks but this won't help as I'd like to keep other accents from the origian stirng.

Comment: @AntoineDusséaux Right, I didn't thought about that. The other answer seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing accents, I needed to preserve accents on the text, then I used the following code:

```
accents_dic = {
'A': '(A|Á|À|Â|Ã)',
'E': '(E|É|È)',
'I': '(I|Í|Ï)',
'O': '(O|Ó|Ô|Õ|Ö)',
'U': '(U|Ú|Ü)',
'C': '(C|Ç)'
}
def define_regex_name(name):
    for i, j in accents_dic.items():
        name = re.sub(i,j,name)
    return re.compile(name, re.IGNORECASE)
```